# Calculating the length of a rope hanging from one point

Tags: arc-length

If you have a rope hanging from one point in the air, how can you calculate the length of it (without measuring it). I don’t really know anything that complicated about maths, but I’m curious if it is possible. The only information you have are two other point that the rope touches, for context see it as a liana from which you swing from one point to the other. I guess it has something to do with the arc length and such, but just a way to calculate the formula of the curve that the end of the rope makes would also help.

Comment: This is not clear.  A rope hanging from one point would just be a straight line down, right?  If you meant that it was hanging between two points, then this is a [Catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary).

Comment: Yeah sorry, I can’t english very good, but what I want to know is if it is possible to calculate the length of the rope by using a few points on the curve

Comment: [this article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Catenary.html) on catenaries includes formulas for the arclength.